# Is this proof correct? $|u \cdot v| = |u | |v |$ IFF one vector is a scalar multiple of the other.

Tags: linear-algebra, proof-writing, vectors, solution-verification

I am working my way through a linear algebra book and would appreciate some help verifying my proof.

**Prove that $|u \cdot v| = |u | |v |$ if and only if one vector is a scalar multiple of the
other.**

**PROOF:**

Let $k ∈ ℝ$ and $u ,v \in\mathbb R^n$ and $~u =k~v$

ASSUME: $|u\cdot v| = |u | |v |$

our assumption holds IFF  $|kv \cdot v| = |kv | |v |$

which again holds IFF $k|v \cdot v| = k|v | |v |$

and, by definition of the dot product, holds IFF $k|v|^2 = k|v |^2$

Q.E.D.

Comment: $u\cdot v =|u| |v| \cos\theta$

Comment: @J.W. Tanner. I am aware of this but why are you posting this under my proof? Do you agree with the user below that this proof is incorrect?

Comment: I agree with the below that your proof is incomplete, and I thought what I posted could help

Answer (score 1):

It is not right.

I don't see any attempt to check what happens if $u$ is not a multiple of $v$.

It would be helpful if you can use $u.v = \|u\|\|v\|\cos \theta$.

Comment: So, are you saying that I do not prove the other "direction" of the IFF statement? I am confused. I thought that a valid technique was to start with the thing one is trying to prove, show equivalence all the way down, and then end with a obviously true statement.

Comment: first line: You started with $|u\cdot v|=|u||v|$ and in the very next line, you again "assume" the setting that one vector is a scalar multiple of another vector. you are suppose to "prove" that one vector is a scalar multiple of another vector.  Another possibility that you can adopt is you assume $|u\cdot v|=|u||v|$ and consider two cases, case $1$, check what happens if $u$ is a multiple of $v$ and case $2$: check what happens if $u$ is not a multiple of $v$. Also, it is not clear what do you mean by $k=k$ is clearly true. $k$ is always equal to $k$ but why is it mentioned.

Comment: why cant I just assume one vector is a scalar multiple of another vector? the question asked me to prove something if and only if one vector is a scalar multiple of the other.I end with k=k becuase I am trying to get the my starting assumption to become something that is clearly true. Ive seen a lot of proofs end with similar statements

Comment: Suppose we live in a world where there are two apples and all apples are tasty but someone claim that "an apple is tasy iff it is red". you need to check both red apples and green apples to verify it.

Answer (score 1):

Let's make the proof of CS explicit to show @CSquared's answer doesn't require circularity. In fact, it's simpler to run through the proof of CS rather than invoking it, as we don't need to check two directions separately.

Write $f(k):=u-kv$ so$$0\le|f(k)|^2=f(k)\cdot f(k)=|u|^2+k^2|v|^2-2ku\cdot v,$$with equality iff $f(k)=0$ i.e. $u=kv$. (You can see where this is going: it involves the convention for $k$ used in the OP, which CSquared reverses.) The special case $k:=v\cdot u/|v|^2$ gives $0\le|u|^2-|u\cdot v|^2/|v|^2$, which rearranges to $|u\cdot v|^2\ge|u|^2|v|^2$, again with equality iff $u=kv$. Now just take the square root.

(The above proof actually works even on complex spaces, due to the careful use of $v\cdot u$ at one point instead of $u\cdot v$, and of $|u\cdot v|^2$ instead of $(u\cdot v)^2$.)

Answer (score 0):

In your proof, you make the assumption that $\vec{u}=k\vec{v}$ and $|\vec{u}\cdot\vec{v}|=||\vec{u}||\,||\vec{v}||$ and then claim that this holds when $$|\vec{u}\cdot\vec{v}|=||\vec{u}||\,||\vec{v}|| \Longleftrightarrow |k\vec{v}\cdot\vec{v}|=||k\vec{v}||\,||\vec{v}||\Longleftrightarrow k|\vec{v}\cdot\vec{v}|=k||\vec{v}||\,||\vec{v}||=k||\vec{v}||^2$$ This demonstrates the $\Leftarrow $ direction, that is, assuming the far right conditions, then we can arrive at the far left condition, but you have not shown that the far left condition implies the far right conditions. This proof uses an assumption which is supposed to be proved when you suggest that $\vec{u}=k\vec{v}$ and $|\vec{u}\cdot\vec{v}|=||\vec{u}||\,||\vec{v}||\Longrightarrow |k\vec{v}\cdot\vec{v}|=||k\vec{v}||\,||\vec{v}||$, which is the statement you are trying to prove.

Here is how I went about proving this:

$\Rightarrow$ direction: Suppose $|\vec{u}\cdot \vec{v}|=||\vec{u}||\,||\vec{v}||$. We want to show that one vector is a scalar multiple of the other. Let  $$\vec{u}=\begin{bmatrix}u_1\\u_2\\\vdots\\u_n \end{bmatrix}, \vec{v}=\begin{bmatrix}v_1\\v_2\\\vdots\\v_n \end{bmatrix}$$
Then we have that $$\begin{align}|\vec{u}\cdot\vec{v}|&=|u_1v_1+u_2v_2+...+u_nv_n|\end{align}$$
and
$$\begin{align}||\vec{u}||\,||\vec{v}||&=\sqrt{(u_1^2+u_2^2+...+u_n^2)(v_1^2+v_2^2+...+v_n^2)}\end{align} $$

This implies that $$(u_1v_1+u_2v_2+...+u_nv_n)^2=(u_1^2+u_2^2+...+u_n^2)(v_1^2+v_2^2+...+v_n^2)$$  but by the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality, $$(u_1v_1+u_2v_2+...+u_nv_n)^2\leq(u_1^2+u_2^2+...+u_n^2)(v_1^2+v_2^2+...+v_n^2)$$ with equality if and only if $\vec{u}$ and $\vec{v}$ are linearly dependent, or in other words, without loss of generality, $\vec{v}=k\vec{u}$.

$\Leftarrow$ direction: Assume vectors $\vec{u}$ and $\vec{v}$ are linearly dependent, that is, without loss of generality, $\vec{v}=k\vec{u}$ for some $k\in\mathbb{R}$. Then, $$|\vec{u}\cdot\vec{v}|=|\vec{u}\cdot k\vec{u}|=|k|\,||\vec{u}||\,||\vec{u}||=||\vec{v}||\,||\vec{u}||$$

Others have suggested using $|\vec{u}\cdot\vec{v}|=||\vec{u}||\,||\vec{v}||\,\cos\theta$ where $\theta$ represents the angle between the two vectors and demonstrating that $\cos\theta=1$ when $\theta =0+2\pi r$ for some $r\in\mathbb{Z}$, which implies that the vectors are parallel and that they are linearly dependent.

Comment: But is not Cauchy-Schwarz proved using the same fact that you have used? I think this is a circular argument.

Comment: @PopularPower I don't believe so . See at the bottom of proof $2$ here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%E2%80%93Schwarz_inequality  I am double checking right now, but I can revise it if it is circular.