# Show that$ |u | = |v |$ if and only if $u +v$ and $u −v$ are perpendicular?

Tags: linear-algebra, proof-writing, vectors, solution-verification

Does this proof look correct? I am new to writing proofs and I keep making mistakes. please verify correct or incorrectness and then give suggestions.

**Show that$ |u | = |v |$ if and only if $u +v$ and $u −v$ are perpendicular.**

if $u +v$ and $u −v$ are perpendicular then  $(u +v)\cdot (u −v)=0$

and by distributive property of the dot product $(u\cdot u)+(u\cdot -v)+(v\cdot u)+(v\cdot −v)=0$

and then $(u\cdot u)-(u\cdot v)+(u\cdot v)-(v\cdot v)=(u\cdot u)-(v\cdot v)=0$

thus $(u\cdot u)=(v\cdot v)$

and from the definition of the dot product and length of a vector we get$|u |^2 = |v |^2$

and then by taking the square root of both sides we get $ |u | = |v |$

the same holds going in the other direction:
if $ |u | = |v |$ then $(u\cdot u)-(v\cdot v)=0$

and $(u\cdot u)-(u\cdot v)+(u\cdot v)-(v\cdot v)=0$

so, $(u\cdot u)+(u\cdot -v)+(v\cdot u)+(v\cdot −v)=0$

and $(u +v)\cdot (u −v)=0$

thus $u +v$ and $u −v$ are perpendicular.

Q.E.D.

Comment: Yes, it's correct. Though you could have done both directions at once by noting that all the implications you used are actually equivalences.

Comment: Small comments: 1) A standard notation for the inner product is $\langle u, v \rangle$ (`\langle u, v \rangle`). 2) All your transitions work in both directions. I.e. instead of writing $\langle u+v, u-v \rangle =0 \implies \ldots \implies |u| = |v|$ you can write $\langle u+v, u-v \rangle =0 \iff \ldots \iff |u| = |v|$, which reduces your work by a factor of 2.

Comment: @Dmitry I appreciate your reply a lot. You say that I can reduce my work by a factor of 2 by doing what you suggest, but on my other proof I was told I was incorrect for not proving in both directions

Comment: can you take a look at     https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3805745/is-this-proof-correct-u-cdot-v-u-v-iff-one-vector-is-a-scalar-mult/3805762?noredirect=1#comment7844442_3805762

Comment: or @Vercassivelaunos I would appreciate if you looked as well.

Comment: @samjenkins, your reasoning in that question look like this: $u=kv \implies (|u \cdot v| = |u| |v| \iff \ldots \iff k |v|^2 = k |v|^2)$. So there is no proof that $|u \cdot v| = |u| |v| \implies u=kv$. It's simply not there.

Comment: Please do not type variables with `~` before them e.g. `~u` and `~u+~v`. It is messing up the spacing that is correctly and automatically done for you when you type mathematics in MathJax

Comment: Geometrically, we can consider the parallelogram whose consecutive sides are $u$ and $v$. If $|u|=|v|$ the parallelogram is a rhombus and so its diagonals $u+v$ and $u-v$ are perpendicular. Conversely, if the diagonals $u+v$ and $u-v$ are perpendicular, the parallelogram is a rhombus, so $|u|=|v|$.

Comment: What would you do if I was actually autistic?  I don't care that much. Just thought you'd like to know how to use the software correctly...

Answer (score 3):

Another way to write your proof:

> *Proof*. Note that
> $$(u+v) \vcenter{\,{\tiny \bullet}\,} (u-v) = u \vcenter{\,{\tiny \bullet}\,} u - u \vcenter{\,{\tiny \bullet}\,} v + v \vcenter{\,{\tiny \bullet}\,} u - v \vcenter{\,{\tiny \bullet}\,} v = |u|^2-|v|^2.$$
> So, if $|u|=|v|$, the above equation implies that $u+v$ and $u-v$ are perpendicular. Conversely, if $u+v$ and $u-v$ are perpendicular, the above equation implies that $|u|^2 = |v|^2$, and so $|u| = |v|$.

Comment: Geometrically, we can consider the parallelogram whose consecutive sides are $u$ and $v$. If $|u|=|v|$ the parallelogram is a rhombus and so its diagonals $u+v$ and $u-v$ are perpendicular. Conversely, if the diagonals $u+v$ and $u-v$ are perpendicular, the parallelogram is a rhombus, so $|u|=|v|$.

Comment: @Angelo Nice, I like it.

Comment: How do you prove the orthogonality of the diagonals of a rhombus ?

Answer (score 2):

Geometrically, we can consider the parallelogram whose consecutive sides are the vectors $u$ and $v$ applied to the same point (which will be a vertex of the parallelogram).

If $|u|=|v|$ the parallelogram is a rhombus and so its diagonals $u+v$ and $u-v$ are perpendicular.

Conversely, if the diagonals $u+v$ and $u-v$ are perpendicular, the parallelogram is a rhombus, so $|u|=|v|$.